# Change my ggplot code to only show half court

Tags: r

I have found code for creating a basketball court in R, but I only want to see half of the court. Right now, it is showing the full court if you run this code, but how do I cut it in half?

```
plot1 <-ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1,y=1),aes(x,y))+
  ###outside box:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-25,-25,25,25,-25),y=c(-47,47,47,-47,-47)))+
  ###halfcourt line:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-25,25),y=c(0,0)))+
  ###halfcourt semicircle:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=c(sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=-c(sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  ###solid FT semicircle above FT line:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=c(28-sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=-c(28-sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  ###dashed FT semicircle below FT line:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=c(28+sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y),linetype='dashed')+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000),y=-c(28+sqrt(6^2-c(-6000:(-1)/1000,1:6000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y),linetype='dashed')+
  ###key:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-8,-8,8,8,-8),y=c(47,28,28,47,47)))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=-c(-8,-8,8,8,-8),y=-c(47,28,28,47,47)))+
  ###box inside the key:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6,-6,6,6,-6),y=c(47,28,28,47,47)))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-6,-6,6,6,-6),y=-c(47,28,28,47,47)))+
  ###restricted area semicircle:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-4000:(-1)/1000,1:4000/1000),y=c(41.25-sqrt(4^2-c(-4000:(-1)/1000,1:4000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-4000:(-1)/1000,1:4000/1000),y=-c(41.25-sqrt(4^2-c(-4000:(-1)/1000,1:4000/1000)^2))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  ###rim:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-750:(-1)/1000,1:750/1000,750:1/1000,-1:-750/1000),y=c(c(41.75+sqrt(0.75^2-c(-750:(-1)/1000,1:750/1000)^2)),c(41.75-sqrt(0.75^2-c(750:1/1000,-1:-750/1000)^2)))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-750:(-1)/1000,1:750/1000,750:1/1000,-1:-750/1000),y=-c(c(41.75+sqrt(0.75^2-c(-750:(-1)/1000,1:750/1000)^2)),c(41.75-sqrt(0.75^2-c(750:1/1000,-1:-750/1000)^2)))),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  ###backboard:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-3,3),y=c(43,43)),lineend='butt')+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-3,3),y=-c(43,43)),lineend='butt')+
  ###three-point line:
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-22,-22,-22000:(-1)/1000,1:22000/1000,22,22),y=c(47,47-169/12,41.75-sqrt(23.75^2-c(-22000:(-1)/1000,1:22000/1000)^2),47-169/12,47)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-22,-22,-22000:(-1)/1000,1:22000/1000,22,22),y=-c(47,47-169/12,41.75-sqrt(23.75^2-c(-22000:(-1)/1000,1:22000/1000)^2),47-169/12,47)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  ###fix aspect ratio to 1:1
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: A simple way is to reduce the [plot limits](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html).

Comment: Only reducing the plot limits cuts away the `geom_path`'s that goes to the other halves, its needed to adjust the box also.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `+ ylim(0,50)` at the end, and change the outside box to `geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(-25,-25,25,25),y=c(0,47,47,0)))`

Output:
[image]